# Padding not respected on mobile email

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, email-client

I have an email which looks great on laptop/desktops, but for some reason the padding is lost on iOS and Android clients.

Here's some screenshots.

**WEB (Gmail)**

[image]

**MOBILE** (iOS)

[image]

Full HTML code can be found here (a few lines shown below to pass SO filters):

http://jsfiddle.net/timrpeterson/3fpjddz5/

```
<body style="background:rgb(251,252,253);padding: 0; width: 100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;" >
```

Comment: check your code in validator, you have too many errors. Also, make your mind, you use HTML5 or you use html transitional (recommended), but not both at the same time, much less when you don't declare a doctype

Comment: I did check with a validator. The errors aren't real errors, but rather about deprecated attributes.

Comment: not all of them, you have real errors. And those deprecated attributes show because you're mixing doctypes, hence why I said you need to define what do you want to do

Comment: Thanks, but correcting the errors and using the transitional doctype doesn't affect the padding.

Comment: Might you have any email templates that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late to the party here, but you can fix this by adding padding to the `<td>` that wraps the content:  [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fpjddz5/1/)